# Querying by near, sorting, then paging

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using the geospatial "near" search in MongoDB (using the C# driver) to return homes within 25 miles of a given lat/long. This returns the homes sorted by proximity to the lat/long and works great.

However, I want to add in sorting (on other fields such as home price) and paging and here is where I'm getting stuck. To work correctly, it would need to figure out which homes were within 25 miles of the lat/long, then sort those results (let's say based on price), and then take a "page" of 10 results.

Below is what I have so far, the issue with it is it takes a page of results (based on the proximity sort) and then sorts that page of 10 results by what I set in "SetSortOrder" rather than sorting the entire result near the lat/long, so each page of 10 results is sorted in itself.

```
var coordinates = find.GetCoordinates();
var near = Query.Near("Coordinates", coordinates.Latitude,
    coordinates.Longitude,
    find.GetRadiansAway(), false);
var query = Collection().Find(near); 
query.Skip = find.GetSkip();
query.Limit = find.GetLimit();
query.SetSortOrder(new string[] { "Price" });
var results = query.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is right behavior, because [$near](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) by default return result sorted by distance. And sorting done internally in $near operator, so you can't change it.

> db.places.find( { loc : { $near :
>   [50,50] } } )
>
> The above query finds the closest
>   points to (50,50) and returns them
>   sorted by distance (there is no need
>   for an additional sort parameter)

So in you example `Price` it's second sort field that sort data within result sorted by distance.

Workgraund is load entire result of `Query.Near` and than sort it by whatever you want field on the client.